# OpenID Connect authentication requests restricted

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I'm facing the problem with configuring OAuth2 login for my application https://github.com/Cruelkid/guitar-cloud/tree/develop

```
2023-04-02T11:52:28.856+03:00 DEBUG 3866 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters   : Start processing with input [response_type=code&client_id=guitar-cloud-client&scope=openid&state=P3j3mwpUvm1UR_tVYjWelCDGauVZxf4ZOOcUyFVSc00%3D&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8080/login/oauth2/code/guitar-cloud-client-oidc&nonce=D-qBrlre2P-il99B1HW8ejFWfMR1fQHB2QG7WRHydNc]
2023-04-02T11:52:28.857+03:00 DEBUG 3866 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] .s.a.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher : No event was found for the exception org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.authentication.OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationException
2023-04-02T11:52:28.857+03:00 DEBUG 3866 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/login/oauth2/code/guitar-cloud-client-oidc?error=invalid_scope&error_description=OpenID%20Connect%201.0%20authentication%20requests%20are%20restricted.&error_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdatatracker.ietf.org%2Fdoc%2Fhtml%2Frfc6749%23section-4.1.2.1&state=P3j3mwpUvm1UR_tVYjWelCDGauVZxf4ZOOcUyFVSc00%3D`
```

Before ending up with such code I was facing similar issue but with an auth server, but i've figured out that this was related to disabled by default OIDC 1.0, but that error was fixed with adding this piece of code:

```
http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
                .oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());
```

Unfortunatelly, for the api client i haven't found a way to do something similar

Answer (score 0):

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class MyAuthorizationServerConfig {
    @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(
            HttpSecurity http, RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository,
            AuthorizationServerSettings authorizationServerSettings) throws Exception {

        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);

        http
                .exceptionHandling((exceptions) -> exceptions
                        .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
                                new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"),
                                new MediaTypeRequestMatcher(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                        )
                )
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2ResourceServer ->
                        oauth2ResourceServer.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));


        http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
                .oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).